# Drupal: How to make a form that captures a value from $_REQUEST[]

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

This is a clone of: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47865/how-to-make-a-form-that-captures-a-value-from-request (currently no answers)

I have been trying to make a form that captures a value passed in from `$_REQUEST`.

1. A field is displayed only if a $_REQUEST variable exists (done)
2. The user can modify the field
3. The field is validated in whatever way
4. The (modified) value gets used

In this specific case, I am using a `hook_user` function, but I hope that the solution is applicable to any Drupal form.

Here's a simplified version of my code where the user would have an extra field to specify that they have a favorite fruit if they were to register using the following URL:

http://example.com/user/register?fruit=pineapple

```
function fruity_user($op, &$edit, &$user, $category = NULL){
    switch($op) {
        // Add extra fields if $_REQUEST contains values for them
        case 'register':
            if($_REQUEST['fruit'] == 'pineapple'){
                $fields['user_reg_info']['profile_fruit'] = array(
                     '#type' => 'textfield'
                    ,'#description' => 'Your favorite fruit (if applicable)'
                    ,'#locked' => 0
                    ,'#value' => $_REQUEST['fruit']
                );
            }
            return $fields;
            break;

        // check registration for mistakes
        case 'validate':
            if ($edit['form_id'] == 'user_register') {
                if ($edit['profile_fruit']){
                    verify_fruit($edit['profile_fruit']);
                }
            }
            break;

        // runs after the new user is inserted
        case 'insert':
            if($_REQUEST['fruit']){
                db_query('INSERT INTO user_fruits SET `uid`=%d `fruit`="%s"',array($user->uid, $edit['profile_fruit']));
            }

            // record information
            watchdog('user', t('user %user picked out a fruit',array('%user' => $user->name)));
            break;
    }
}
```

With the above code, the field does make itself visible only when `$_REQUEST['fruit']`  is present but if you change your fruit to "watermelon" on the form, `insert` still uses "pineapple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use `#default_value` instead of `#value`.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#default_value

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using two different keys while inserting and registering. You are using $fields['user_reg_info']['profile_fruit'] in register and $edit['fruit'] in insert. Try using ['fruit'] key in both the places. Also use the same in edit.

Comment: Ahhh That was a mistake on my part when I simplified my code into an example block. Thanks for the heads-up. I updated the example to match the structure of my problem exactly. You make an interesting point though! Sould I use `$edit['user_reg_info']['fruit']` instead of `$edit['fruit']`?